# GAE datastore query ConjunctionNode error

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a ndb model in datastore with two fields - expired and expiry besides other details such as bookname, author etc.

```
class Books(ndb.Model):  
     expiry = ndb.IntegerProperty() #epoch
     expired = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False) # set True if expiry < curr_time
```

I have written cron.yaml and cron.py to mark `expired=True` for finding the books where the `expiry < curr_time`.

Following is my cron.py snippet:

```
    from google.appengine.api import search
    import logging
    from models.books import Books
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb
    import time

    def deleteindex(cls):
           curr_time = int(time.time()) + 60
           #find the books which have expired but not marked expired. 
           expired_books = Books.query(ndb.AND(Books.expiry < curr_time, not Books.expired)) 
           print expired_books
```

However, I am getting error :

> File "/home/hduser/Documents/GCP/book-shelf453/default/app/cron.py", line 16, in deleteindex
>
> expired_books = Books.query(ndb.AND(Books.expiry < curr_time, not Books.expired))
>     File "/home/hduser/Documents/GCP/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 583, in **new**
>       ' received a non-Node instance %r' % node)
>
> TypeError: ConjunctionNode() expects Node instances as arguments; received a non-Node instance False

I am not sure about the issue here. Please suggest ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndb query filters must consist of comparisons between a model property and a value - for example between `Books.expiry` and an `int`.

`not Books.expired` is not such a comparison, and this is the cause of the error.

Instead of negating `Books.expired`, compare it to a boolean.

This should work:

`expired_books = Books.query(ndb.AND(Books.expiry < curr_time, Books.expired != False))`

Comment: That worked, thanks.! I had to modify a little bit as `expired_books = Books.query(ndb.AND(Books.expiry < curr_time, Books.expired == True))` as GAE complained about supporting only one inequality query at a time.